# Why do I get infinity when I compute the Weingarten Map of the cone?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am a newbie to differential geometry and I am learning on my own. In a practice problem, I tried to compute the Weingarten map for the standard cone parametrized as $ x(u, v) = (v \cos u ,v \sin u, v) $.

All goes fine, except when I want the explicit representation of the Weingarten map, I am getting some infinities. Is there something wrong with the $ 3 \times 3 $ representation of the Weingarten map, or should I always compute it on the tangent surface only?

Here is a link to what I have done. I typesetted all the equations there so I will not repeat here.

http://andrew-exercise.blogspot.com/2016/01/differential-geometry-and-its_48.html

Just before this, I am done a similar problem on a cone, and it worked smoothly, I have got the $ 3 \times 3 $ representation of the Weingarten map there.

http://andrew-exercise.blogspot.com/2016/01/differential-geometry-and-its_38.html

So, just to be clear, the question is :

Why am I getting infinity when I compute the Weingarten map of the standard cone?

Comment: The Gauss map is a map from the surface $S$ to the unit sphere, and so its derivative should be given by a $2\times 2$ matrix once you work with a parametrization of the surface (remembering that at any point $p$ the derivative maps the tangent plane $T_p S$ to itself (because the tangent plane to the sphere at $n(p)$ is also $T_p S$). Thus, you should never have any $3\times 3$ matrices. You might want to look at some standard texts for examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your flaw seems to be in thinking that $$\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^{-1} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial u}.$$

When dealing with partial derivatives you can't just "flip fractions" like this - instead the correct relationship is between the full Jacobian matrices. In a simplified $2\times 2$ case we have $$\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)} = \left( \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} \right)^{-1}$$
where both sides are $2 \times 2$ matrices and the inverse is the matrix inverse.